# How to parse nested JSON array in android

Tags: android, json, nested

How to  get latitude and longitude object. please help

{

```
"category":[
    {
        "name":"Judging_Point",
        "title":"",
        "iconimg":"33.png",
        "count":0,
        "content":""
    },
    {
        "name":"Street_Trading_Stalls",
        "title":"Street Trading Stalls",
        "iconimg":"34.png",
        "count":0,
        "content":""
    },
    {
        "name":"static_sound_systems",
        "title":"Sound Systems",
        "count":29,
        "iconimg":"24.png",
        "content":[
            {
                "latitude":"51.52603767293402",
                "longitude":" -0.2136941301305184",
                "title":"4 Play",
```

},
 {
                    "latitude":"51.52603767293402",
                    "longitude":" -0.2136941301305184",
                    "title":"4 Play",
},

Comment: What did you try? We won't do your homework.

Comment: Duplicate.. do I need to provide a link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [JSONSimple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) with is a Java JSON lib. Android may contain a json lib allready but i like json simple because its simple:)

Just create a Parser object and read the String.

Then create a JSONObject by getting the "category" and so on

Answer (score -1):

@user3796430 Try integrating GSON library. It will definitely help you...